# when using mv command What is ./

Tags: voip

Thanks to whoever answer.
I'm trying to install VoIPMonitor on Ubuntu12.04..LTS.
Here is the previous command:

```
wget "http://www.voipmonitor.org/download-gui?version=latest&major=5&festry" -O w.tar.gz
tar xzf w.tar.gz
```

-what is `-O w.tar.gz` doing?

Then, the next command is:

```
mv voipmonitor-gui*/* ./
```

Here is where I'm stuck. This command is moving the previous downloaded file and unpacking it to where? What is `./`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`./` is your current working directory, which is `$PWD` == `$(pwd)`.

BTW: -O is output the document to a file. Another form `-O- | xxx` or `-O - | xxx` is also very common, which outputs the downloaded document to stdout and pipe it to other commands.

Answer (score 0):

The software you are downloading from the url given must have been a zipped file.tar is a tool in linux systems (among other zip-unzip tools) which is being used in your command, 
and as stated by @Terry Wang `./` denotes your current directory, so the next command is basically moving your software from the directory where it was unpacked to your current directory

Answer (score 0):

This command downloads a file:

```
wget "http://www.voipmonitor.org/download-gui?version=latest&major=5&festry"
```

If you just run this command on its own, the name of the file that will be downloaded will be `download-gui?version=latest&major=5&festry"`, because that's what `wget` sees in the URL.

The `-O` option allows you to rename the file you're downloading. So `-O w.tar.gz` renames the file to `w.tar.gz`; so basically after the download finishes, you'll find a file called `w.tar.gz`, that's the file you downloaded.

The next command is:

```
tar xzf w.tar.gz
```

Which extracts `w.tar.gz`. It will extract a folder called `voipmonitor-gui-6.0-SVN1062` and a file called `voipmonitor-5.0-SVN-onlyforbackwardcompatibility`.

The next command:

```
mv voipmonitor-gui*/* ./
```

Will move everything from under the folder `voipmonitor-gui-6.0-SVN1062` to the current directory. So `./` means "current directory".

#### Example:

If you've downloaded the file to your Downloads folder, this will be your folder structure after extracting:

```
Downloads/
    voipmonitor-gui-6.0-SVN1062/
          [lots of files]
    voipmonitor-5.0-SVN-onlyforbackwardcompatibility
```

After the move command, you'll move `[lots of files]` to Downloads.

```
Downloads/
    [lots of files]
    voipmonitor-gui-6.0-SVN1062/
          empty
    voipmonitor-5.0-SVN-onlyforbackwardcompatibility
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [mark an answer as your accepted answer](http://www.askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the answer!